# Scheduling a Callable at a fixed rate

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent

I have a task that I want to run at a fixed rate. However I also need the result of the task after each execution. Here is what I tried:

The task

```
class ScheduledWork implements Callable<String>
{
    public String call()
    {
        //do the task and return the result as a String
    }
}
```

No I tried to use the `ScheduledExecutorService` to scheduled it. Turns out you cannot schedule a `Callable` at a fixed rate, only a `Runnable` can be done so.

Please advise.

Comment: or... Instead of waiting for the return value of the Callable, why not handle in it? So you would have a Runnable instead of your Callable and in the Runnable, once you have the value you want to act on, just use it and do what you want.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use a [producer/consumer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer-consumer_problem): Have the Runnable [put](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html#put%28E%29) its result on a [BlockingQueue](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html). Have another thread [take()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html#take%28%29) from the queue.

Take is a blocking call (ie only returns when something is on the queue), so you'll get your results as soon as they're available.

You could combine this with the [hollywood pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hollywood_Principle) to provide the waiting thread with a callback so your code gets called when something is available.

Answer (score -1):

Unless if you don't care about the return value of your `Callable`, you can wrap it in a `Runnable` and use that to pass to `ScheduledExecutorService`.

```
public static Runnable runnableOf(final Callable<?> callable)
{
    return new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                callable.call();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Then when you want to submit to `ScheduledExecutroService` you can pass your `Callable`:

```
ses.scheduleAtFixedRate(runnableOf(callabale), initialDelay, delay, unit);
```