# How to run a submitted task a set number of times with an interval between each one

Tags: java, executorservice, scheduledexecutorservice

I have a function which takes a task and runs it *n* times with a set interval in between each run. It should return a Future which can be used to obtain the result of the task when the task completes.

Here is what I have so far:

```
public <V> Future<V> runTaskAsynchronously(ITask<V> task, int numOfTimes, long sleep) {
    ScheduledExecutorService ses = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(numOfTimes);

    Callable<V> callable = () -> {
        return task.call();
    };
}
```

Each task is an implementation of this interface:

```
public interface ITask<T> {
  /**
   * A task if complete if its objective 
   * has been met through an invokation
   * of the 'call' method.
   * 
   */
  public boolean isComplete();
  
  /**
   * Does the actual work and returns 
   * a result.
   *  
   */
  public T call();
}
```

How can I complete the implementation of the runTaskAsynchronously method? I have tried to use the executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate method but this is only applicable to Runnables and not Callables.

I have looked at [Scheduling a Callable at a fixed rate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7331754/scheduling-a-callable-at-a-fixed-rate), but the BlockingQueue implementation would not work here as I need to return a future.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scheduling a Callable at a fixed rate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7331754/scheduling-a-callable-at-a-fixed-rate)

Comment: Not quite, I don't think the BlockingQueue implementation would work in this instance

Comment: Your question is confusing. A future returns a single value. But you want to schedule the task at a fixed rate, which will return a _stream_ of values. Which value out of those do you want? That's why the linked answer creates a blocking queue. To put these multiple values in.

Comment: If this is for production use then look up how to implement task schedulers. If this is just homework or for proof of concept tasks then any number of solutions will do. The tricky part is not necessarily how to run things in the background asynch but what to do if and when tasks fail... ie. whether or not one run cycle may bump into another or if it locks up or if it exits with Exception or Error. Etc.